# I want to create pygame window but it kept saying "video system not initialized" in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pygame

I am using visualcodestudio, but if I run using python IDLE, it runs.

```
import pygame, sys

def run_game():
    
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200,800))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invasion")


while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        
    
    pygame.display.flip()

run_game()
```

Comment: Looks like the while loop should be included in your `run_game()` function, so if you fix the indentation your code should run.

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize using `pygame.init()` first before going into the loop. Also, I replaced `sys.exit()` with `pygame.quit()` as `sys.exit()` causes the program to not respond with attempting to close the program.

```py
import pygame, sys

def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200,800))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invasion")


run_game()
while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        
    
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Or, you could put the loop *inside* the `run_game()` function as **import random** suggested.

```py
import pygame, sys

def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200,800))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invasion")

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
        
    
        pygame.display.flip()

run_game() # Run the game
```